How to change Laravel Filament Eloquent Query base on a condition?
I have a filament resource with a table. I want to change the table query based on the condition i.e. if there is a filter
->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query){ 
     if (tableFilter) 
        { 
           return $query->with('studentAcademics'); 
        } 
     else
        { 
          return $query->whereNull('id'); 
        } 
    })


How can I check if there is an active table filter?

what is tableFilter?

Which filament are you using ? V2 or V3 ?
For v3 it can be useful this doc sample: Filament tables
By looking at the example you will notice "->filters([" method which handles table data according to the state of "x" column of the table.

@AntonioGocaj I am using "filament/filament": "^3.2.108". What i really want to do is to prevent the table from loading data until a filter is applied

This solved my problem
->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query, Table $table) {
            $filters = $table->getFilters();
            // Check if any filters are applied

          $hasActiveFilters = collect($filters)
                   ->some(function ($filter){
                   return $filter->getActiveCount() > 0;
              });

            if ($hasActiveFilters) {
                // If filters are active, modify the query accordingly
                return $query->with('studentAcademics');
            } else {
                // If no filters are active, apply a different query modification
                return $query->whereNull('id');
            } 
        })


@RajuModal Thanks for the idea you gave. I changed from  $hasActiveFilters = collect($filters)
->some(fn ($filter) => $filter->isActive()); to $hasActiveFilters = collect($filters)
->some(function ($filter){
return $filter->getActiveCount() > 0 ? true:false;
});
